# ASP.NET MVC 3 Basics, trying to get list of all elements that match certain criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC but am having trouble trying to find info on how to do some basic things, so I've given up my search and decided to just ask instead.

Basically I have the start of an MVC3 site that will host various contests.  I want to simply display a list of contests where the end date of the contest is greater than the current date.

My Contest model is defined as:

```
public class Contest
{
    public int ContestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public Boolean Published { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller I am currently using:

```
ViewBag.CurrentContests = db.Contests.ToList();
```

I'm just wondering how to filter the results to just those that haven't 'expired' yet.  This seems like the most basic thing, but maybe I'm just not looking in the right places.  All the tutorials I've been finding either use the `Find()` method to look up a specific row by its id, or just returning all rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some linq-to-entities:

```
db.Contests.Where(c=> c.End > DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

**Note**: When doing date/time comparisons you might have problems because Entity-Framework will generate SQL which will compare the date **and time**.

If you do, you would use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) to fix this like this:

```
db.Contests
  .Where(c=> 
       EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.End) >
                            EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today))
    .ToList();
```